How to align two columns
I want to extraInfo and sunInfo to be side by side but still have all information in both to act as columns. I also want for the humidity and wind speed text to be to the tight of the icons and for sunset and sunrise for the time to be to the right of the icons as well.
I tried using inline-blocks, float, justify-items, and justify-content and none of them worked.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 470px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #00feba, #5b548a);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 40px 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search-bar {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  color: 555;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.search-box button {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-box button img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
}

.weather-icon {
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.weather h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.weather h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.details {
  text-align: center;
}

.sunInfo {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: right;
  align-items: right;
  gap: 20px;
}

.extra-info {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: left;
  gap: 20px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.col img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sunrise img,
.sunset img {
  width: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.humidity,
.wind {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
<div class="container">

  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search for a city..." spellcheck="false">
    <button> <img src="images/search.png"> </button>
  </div>

  <div class="weather">
    <img class="weather-icon" src="images/clear.png">
    <h1 class="temp"> 25°C </h1>
    <h2 class="city">New York</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="details">

    <div class="sunInfo">

      <div class="sunrise">
        <img src="images/sunrise.png">
        <p>6:00 AM</p>
      </div>

      <div class="sunset">
        <img src="images/sunset.png">
        <p>8:00 PM</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="extraInfo">

      <div class="col">
        <img src="images/humidity.png">

        <div>
          <p class="humidity">50%</p>
          <p>Humidity</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <img src="images/wind.png">

        <div>
          <p class="wind">15mph</p>
          <p>Wind Speed</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




To solve your questions, you just need some CSS:
To put the text to the right of the icons:

You need to add inline-block to the image and the text. This can be done with:
.sunrise *, .sunset * {
   display: inline-block;
}


Then, you need to take out the width for the image, so there isn't a huge gap between the two elements:

.col img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sunrise img, .sunset img {
  width: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}




Now, the sunset and sunrise icons are next to the text.
To put the Humidity and Wind Speed next to their stat, add:
.col * {
  display: inline-block;
}

This will put them next to each other, in a line.
Then, to put sunInfo and extraInfo side by side, you change their parent to the style display: flex;
Here it is:
.details {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

This is all the code combined:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 470px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #00feba, #5b548a);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 40px 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search-bar {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  color: 555;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.search-box button {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-box button img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
}

.weather-icon {
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.weather h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.weather h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.details {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.sunInfo {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: right;
  align-items: right;
  gap: 20px;
}

.extra-info {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: left;
  gap: 20px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.col * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.humidity,
.wind {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.sunrise *,
.sunset * {
  display: inline-block;
}
<div class="container">

  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search for a city..." spellcheck="false">
    <button> <img src="images/search.png"> </button>
  </div>

  <div class="weather">
    <img class="weather-icon" src="images/clear.png">
    <h1 class="temp"> 25°C </h1>
    <h2 class="city">New York</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="details">

    <div class="sunInfo">

      <div class="sunrise">
        <img src="images/sunrise.png">
        <p>6:00 AM</p>
      </div>

      <div class="sunset">
        <img src="images/sunset.png">
        <p>8:00 PM</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="extraInfo">

      <div class="col">
        <img src="images/humidity.png">

        <div>
          <p class="humidity">50%</p>
          <p>Humidity</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <img src="images/wind.png">

        <div>
          <p class="wind">15mph</p>
          <p>Wind Speed</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>



Hope this Helps!
